# pandas.DataFrame.to_sql intermittently loading data partially to snowflake/database

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dataloader

Intermittently it happens that pandas.DataFrame.to_sql partially loads data into snowflake.
Example: DF has 25000 rows, buy the function loads only 15000 to snowflake.
Has anyone faced this issue and resolved it. I tried playing with function parameters but the issue persists.

Example: DF has 25000 rows, buy the function loads only 15000 to snowflake.
Has anyone faced this issue and resolved it. I tried playing with function parameters but the issue persists.

Comment: I'd recommend providing relevant code, any error messages received in Snowflake query_history, etc. so that others can help.  All of that said, you should be leveraging `write_pandas` rather than `to_sql` but if you are using `to_sql` are you using `pd_writer` with it?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the chunksize to 500 from 16000 and no issues seen after that for almost a month now.

Comment: You can go ahead and accept your own answer, if you'd like.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).